# Android Animation Clockwise

Tags: java, android, animation

I have the next code for move a image in 360 degree but I want to move the image in certain degree when the I touch the screen. For instance, when the screen is touched the image move in 10 degree in closewise  or anticlosewise direction.
please help me I am stuck with a project. 
I want something like this.
[**In this image you can see how i want to implement.**](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzZCXD7Uqg87ZjJ5bHdPbTI2TFk/edit?pli=1)

Thanks in advance.

MainActivity.java

```
 public class Tablero extends Activity {

    private ImageView imagen;
    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tablero);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tableroTv);

        imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tableroAnimacion);
        imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int numero = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;

                Animation anim = new Animacion(getApplicationContext(),
                        imagen, 300);
                anim.setDuration(3000); 
                imagen.startAnimation(anim);


                tv.setText(numero+"");


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Animation.java

```
 public class Animacion extends Animation {
    private View view;
    private float cx, cy;
    private float prevX, prevY;
    private float r;
    private Context context;
    private float angulo;
    private int cont=0;

    public Animacion(Context context, View view, float r) {
        this.context = context;
        this.view = view;
        this.r = r;
        angulo = 90f;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
            int parentHeight) {
        int cxImage = width / 2;
        int cyImage = height / 2;
        cx = view.getLeft() + cxImage;
        cy = view.getTop() + cyImage;

        prevX = cx;
        prevY = cy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        if (interpolatedTime == 0) {
            return;
        }

        //float angleDeg = (interpolatedTime * 360f + 90) % 360;    

        float angleDeg = (interpolatedTime * 60f + 90) % 360;   
        // float angleDeg = angulo;

        float angleRad = (float) Math.toRadians(angleDeg);

        //Log.d("animacion", "grados " + angleDeg);
        //Log.d("animacion", "radianes " + angleRad);



        float x = (float) (cx + r * Math.cos(angleRad));
        float y = (float) (cy + r * Math.sin(angleRad));

        float dx = prevX - x;
        float dy = prevY - y;

        Log.d("animacion", "x: " + x + " y : " + y
                +" dx: " + dx + " dy: " +dy);


        t.getMatrix().setTranslate(dx, dy);



    }




    public void setAngulo(float grados){
        this.angulo = grados;
    }


    public float getAngulo(){
        return this.angulo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your first steps is going to be detecting touch input and deciding what to do with it. Have a look at this: [OnTouchListener in a View - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506287/ontouchlistener-in-a-view-android)

Basically you want to make your Activity implement the OnTouchListener interface and provide an overridden version of the onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) method. In here you extract the event action and handle it as necessary.

This will also help: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

The ACTION_DOWN event occurs when a user puts their finger on the screen. The ACTION_MOVE event occurs when a user has touched the screen and is moving their finger without lifting it from the screen. ACTION_UP is when the user removes their finger from the screen. The reason I point all of this out is that if you want something to happen while the user holds their finger down and doesn't move it, you will have to have some variable set to true for example when ACTION_DOWN occurs, and false when ACTION_UP occurs. So when the variable is true, the rotation keeps happening, 10 degrees at a time. The other way of course is to have the rotation happen once on ACTION_DOWN and then repeat on ACTION_MOVE as the user moves their finger. You can also call .getX() and .getY() on the MotionEvent variable that will let you know where the user touched and potentially work out what direction they are moving their finger in etc.

Comment: At the moment onTouchListener isn't a problem. Please somebody help me with move the image. Thanks for your help.